# artifact is not uploaded to Nexus repository via curl command

Tags: maven, curl, nexus

Follow instruction on this page:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/22189106-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-

I was able to upload artifact to repository Australia by using this command:

```
curl -v -u admin:admin123 --upload-file RE_0.0.0.19.tar.gz http://nexus1.ccorp.com/nexus/content/repositories/Australia/RE_0.0.0.19.tar.gz
```

That doesn't create POM file or has artifactId associate with, which mean I won't able to query for latest build in that repository.

I then tried this command:

```
curl -v -F r=releases -F hasPom=false -F e=tar.gz -F g=Australia -F a=RE -F v=0.0.0.19 -F p=tar.gz -F file=RE_0.0.0_19.tar.gz -u admin:admin123 http://nexus1.ccorp.com/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content
```

I got this log with no error, but artifact is not uploaded:

Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  Trying 10.10.5.92...
Connected to nexus1.ccorp.com (10.10.5.92) port 80 (#0)
Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
POST /nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: nexus1.ccorp.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 852
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------929d6986ddb3024d

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Tue, 20 Oct 2015 20:29:11 GMT
Server Nexus/2.11.4-01 Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.1.6-SONATYPE-5348-V8 is not blacklisted
Server: Nexus/2.11.4-01 Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.1.6-SONATYPE-5348-V8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 85

Connection #0 to host nexus1.ccorp.com left intact
{"groupId":"Australia","artifactId":"RE","version":"0.0.0.19","packaging":"tar.gz"}

Comment: 'I got this log with no error'

I suggest you add --fail to your curl commands, just to make sure.

http://superuser.com/questions/590099/can-i-make-curl-fail-with-an-exitcode-different-than-0-if-the-http-status-code-i

Comment: Thanks Trent for the suggestion. I re-run both commands with --fail:


I didn't see any different behavior. I still able to upload artifact with first command, and nothing is uploaded with second command.

I do notice something different: while using the first command, there is: 'We are completely uploaded and fine' message which does not displayed while I run second curl command

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
 We are completely uploaded and fine
HTTP/1.1 201 Created

Comment: did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: @user260399 Did you find anything for this issue?